# Screen freezing with diagonal lines Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, freeze

I'm new to Ubuntu. I installed 16.04 and everything seemed to work well at first. However, now the screen will freeze up with diagonal colored lines. The only way to recover appears to be by holding the power button until the machine shuts down and then powering back on. Sometimes, I can use the computer for an hour or so before the screen freezes. Other times, it freezes right away. My computer is a Compaq Presario SR5710F. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please tell us about the graphics chip/card: brand name and model. It will help us help you.

Comment: Integrated graphics using nVidia GeForce 6150SE   Chipset: NVIDIA GeForce 6150SE nForce 430

Comment: This card was released June 2006, and there might be problems to find a good driver for it. It might be a good idea to try 1) with a proprietary nvidia driver. 2)the older version Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS without and with a proprietary nvidia driver. 3) Try flavours of Ubuntu with a lighter desktop environment: Lubuntu, Xubuntu and Ubuntu MATE. -  Try the other version and the other flavours *live* (booted from USB or DVD) without installing, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389

Comment: I tried using the Nvdia driver, installing 14.04 with and without the Nvidia driver and also installing Lubuntu.  The Nvidia driver causes an inescapable login loop. Everything else resulted in intermittent screen freezing with diagonal lines. I'm planning to get a new graphics card for this machine. Are there any brands that tend to work better than others with Ubuntu? Are there brands/models I should avoid, or will pretty much any new graphics card work?

Comment: The linux community has had time to develop a driver for cards that have been in the market for some time. Brand new cards might be tricky. You can read threads  or create an own thread at the Ubuntu Hardware Forum, https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=332 or just search the internet for "select ubuntu graphics card" (without quotes). - I have an nvidia card in my main computer, and it works well for me. It is not new, but not as old as your card (yet too old to be recommended).